# Profiling on live Django server?

Tags: python, django, code-coverage

I've never done code coverage in Python, but I'm looking for something like `GCC`'s `gcov`, which tells me how many times each line executes, or Apple's Shark which gives a hierarchial breakdown of how long each function is taking.

My problem is that I have a live server which is experiencing high load, and I can't tell from the logs what's causing it. I would like to attach something to my Django instance to monitor which lines are the hottest and/or which functions are taking the longest time.

This is something like, but not exactly, code coverage. I would like to introduce it to a live running server, preferably without modifying too much.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cProfile + RunSnakeRun: 
http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/

Comment: How do I attach cProfile to a running Django process?

Comment: You can't attach profiler to running process. You need to start django process from `cProfile.py`: http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#instant-user-s-manual

Comment: Yep, the answer was to fiddle with my launch scripts and put this in. Not very intrusive.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[Django-live-profiler](http://invitebox.github.com/django-live-profiler/) is a drop-in Django app that lets you profile your running application using [statprof](https://github.com/bos/statprof.py) and visualize the results.

Answer (score 1):

I use this pattern: A monitor threads writes stacktraces to a log file every 0.3 seconds. After some hours I can see where the interpreter spends the most time. It does not slow down the my server:

[Live Profiling of Python Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458170/live-profiling-of-python-server/12458172)