# Live Profiling of Python Server

Tags: python, django, profiling, live

I want to know where the python interpreter spends the most time. I use it on a live django application, but it should work for all long running python processes.

I answer my own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os, re, sys, time, datetime, collections, thread, threading, atexit, traceback 

u'''

debug_live.start(seconds_float) starts a monitor thread which print 
the stacktrace of all threads into a logfile.
You can report which lines are executed the most with this script:

app_foo_d@server:~$ python djangotools/utils/debug_live.py -h
usage: debug_live.py [-h] [--most-common N] {sum-all-frames,sum-last-frame}

Read stacktrace log

positional arguments:
  {sum-all-frames,sum-last-frame}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --most-common N       Display the N most common lines in the stacktraces

---------------------------------

You can start the watching thread your django middleware like this:

class FOOMiddleware:
    def __init__(self):
        u'This code gets executed once after the start of the wsgi worker process. Not for every request!'
        seconds=getattr(settings, 'debug_live_interval', None)
        if seconds:
            seconds=float(seconds)
            from djangotools.utils import debug_live
            debug_live.start(seconds)

# settings.py
debug_live_interval=0.3 # ever 0.3 second

# Inspired by http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques

You can get a simple report of the log file of stacktraces like below. The lines
which are not from django are marked with "<====". That's most likely your code
and this could be a bottle neck.

python ..../debug_live.py read
 1971 File: "/home/foo_bar_p/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 272, in __call__
      response = self.get_response(request)
 1812 File: "/home/foo_bar_p/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
      response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 1725 File: "/home/foo_bar_p/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 44, in execute
      return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
 1724 File: "/home/foo_bar_p/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 735, in execute_sql
      cursor.execute(sql, params)
 1007 File: "/home/foo_bar_p/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 680, in results_iter
      for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  796 File: "/home/foo_bar_p/django/db/models/query.py", line 273, in iterator
      for row in compiler.results_iter():
  763 File: "/home/foo_bar_p/foo/utils/ticketutils.py", line 135, in __init__      <====
      filter=type_filter(root_node=self.root_node)
  684 File: "/home/foo_bar_p/django/db/models/query.py", line 334, in count
      return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  679 File: "/home/foo_bar_p/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 367, in get_aggregation
      result = query.get_compiler(using).execute_sql(SINGLE)
  677 File: "/home/foo_bar_p/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 401, in get_count
      number = obj.get_aggregation(using=using)[None]


'''


from django.conf import settings

outfile = os.path.expanduser('~/tmp/debug_live.log')

other_code=re.compile(r'/(django|python...)/')


def stacktraces():
    code=[]
    now=datetime.datetime.now()
    pid=os.getpid()
    my_thread_id=thread.get_ident()
    for thread_id, stack in sys._current_frames().items(): 
        if thread_id==my_thread_id:
            continue # Don't print this monitor thread
        code.append("\n\n#START date: %s\n# ProcessId: %s\n# ThreadID: %s" % (now, pid, thread_id))
        for filename, lineno, name, line in traceback.extract_stack(stack): 
            code.append('File: "%s", line %d, in %s' % (filename, lineno, name)) 
            if line: 
                code.append("  %s" % (line.strip()))
        code.append('#END')
    if not code:
        return
    fd=open(outfile, 'at')
    fd.write('\n'.join(code))
    fd.close()

def monitor(interval):
    while monitor_thread:
        stacktraces()
        time.sleep(interval)

monitor_thread=None

def exiting():
    global monitor_thread
    monitor_thread=None


def start(interval):
    global monitor_thread
    if monitor_thread:
        return
    assert not os.path.islink(outfile), outfile # well known temporary name.... symlink attack...
    monitor_thread = threading.Thread(target=monitor, args=[interval])
    monitor_thread.setDaemon(True)
    atexit.register(exiting)
    monitor_thread.start()

def read_logs(args):
    # The outfile can be huge, don't read the whole file into memory.
    counter=collections.Counter()
    cur_stack=[]
    py_line=''
    code_line=''
    if args.action=='sum-all-frames':
        sum_all_frames=True
    else:
        sum_all_frames=False
    for line in open(outfile):
        if line.startswith('#END'):
            if sum_all_frames:
                frames=cur_stack
            else:
                frames=cur_stack[-1:]
            counter.update(frames)
            cur_stack=[]
            continue
        if line[0] in '\n#':
            continue
        if line.startswith('File:'):
            py_line=line.rstrip()
            continue
        if line.startswith(' '):
            code_line=line.rstrip()
            if not (py_line, code_line) in cur_stack:
                # If there is a recursion, count the line only once per stacktrace
                cur_stack.append((py_line, code_line))
            continue
        print 'ERROR unparsed', line
    for (py, code), c in counter.most_common(args.most_common):
        if not other_code.search(py):
            py='%s      <====' % py
        print '% 5d %s\n    %s' % (c, py, code)

def main():
    import argparse
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Read stacktrace log')
    parser.add_argument('action', choices=['sum-all-frames', 'sum-last-frame'])
    parser.add_argument('--most-common', metavar='N', default=30, type=int, help='Display the N most common lines in the stacktraces')
    args=parser.parse_args()
    return read_logs(args)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: + I'm impressed. I assume the traces are grabbed at intervals, rather than at entry/exit events, and I assume the number on the left is the number of traces containing that line. My only suggestion would be to select 10 or 20 of the traces at "random" and let the user study them. Nice work.

Comment: All traces are in ~/tmp/debug_live.log you can study all traces there.... I found some hot spots in my app. And they where not where I thought I need to optimize.

Comment: Right, that's the fun thing. It's almost always a surprise. What I find is sure you can get a long way with simple statement frequency, but for high power tuning, it's best to apply your intellect to whole traces. You can only do that for a small number of traces, but a small number of traces is good enough, because anything big enough to be worth fixing will show up in them, provided they are more or less random. [*Here's why*](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262) if you like math.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wsgi-shell The 'ispyd' package provides an in process shell for introspecting a running process.