# How to profile a running Django application?

Tags: python, django, profiling

My large Django application is taking up 30-60 MB of RAM while running, and up to 40% CPU. How can I monitor and profile my application on the fly to determine where my potential memory and cpu leaks are?

Comment: turning on debug mode will not display cpu or memory profiling.

Comment: The idea was if debug was true, this will cause lots of performance problems.

Comment: ah. debug is off, but thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this: [profiling Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ProfilingDjango), might come handy. There is also a link to [hotshot](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hotshot.html), which I used in the past. I was able to improve some stuff with hotshot. Also [newrelic](http://newrelic.com/) can be useful.

Some similar questions:

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213007/profiling-on-live-django-server), 
[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361985/profiling-django)